# How to return the selected text from a certain column in a listview

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to copy the text from a certain column. When the user selects a row, I need to return the value of another column in that row, how do I accomplish this.

```
main.window_id = ListView1.SelectedItems(1).Text
```

***main.window_id is a variable from another Form

Possible values I want to return (Image):

https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1PPShBuy3mX_FwUV4LnXxmu3Q7BwJA-yQUZUg6I4CUZU/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
main.window_id = ListView1.SelectedItems[itemIndex].SubItems[1].Text
```

Comment: Thanks, that partially solved my problem but there is an error when I try `main.window_id = ListView1.SelectedItems(1).SubItems(1).Text` it returns InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'. Thanks

Comment: if there is only one subitem the index will have to be 0 instead of 1.